# Load Google Maps External Javascript Before Skin Javascript

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, google-map

I'm trying to add the Google Maps Javascript API to my Magento module.

The problem I'm having is that the `core/text` block that I am including, that contains the external Javascript inclusion tag, only ever appears after all of the `addJs` actions.

This means the script I have in `pvtl_stores.js` that targets the `google` object doesn't work as the `google` object hasn't been initialized yet.

Here is my `local.xml` file:

```
<layout>
<default>
    <reference name="head">

        <block type="core/text" name="google.maps" before="root">
            <action method="setText">
                <text><![CDATA[<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>]]></text>
            </action>
        </block>

        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/pvtl_stores.js</name>
        </action>

    </reference>
 </default>
</layout>
```

Is there a way to have the `core/text` block load before the `addJs` actions?

By the way, if it isn't obvious by the question, I'm new to Magento programming!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My solution (I inspired here - [how to rewrite head.phtml in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373670/how-to-rewrite-head-phtml-in-magento)

rewrite `<head>` in `config.xml`

```
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <page>
                <rewrite>
                    <html_head>Namespace_Modulename_Block_Html_Head</html_head>
                </rewrite>
            </page>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

create file `Head.php` in your `Namespace\Modulename\Blocks\Html` directory
with similiar content

```
class NameSpace_Modulename_Block_Html_Head extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('modulename/html/head.phtml');
    }

   public function getCssJsHtmlBefore() {
    return '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>';
   }

}
```

and create file `head.phtml` in `app/design/frontend/default/template/modulename/html/` directory

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php echo $this->getContentType() ?>" />
<title><?php echo $this->getTitle() ?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getDescription()) ?>" />
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getKeywords()) ?>" />
<meta name="robots" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getRobots()) ?>" />
<link rel="icon" href="<?php echo $this->getFaviconFile(); ?>" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $this->getFaviconFile(); ?>" type="image/x-icon" />
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var BLANK_URL = '<?php echo $this->helper('core/js')->getJsUrl('blank.html') ?>';
    var BLANK_IMG = '<?php echo $this->helper('core/js')->getJsUrl('spacer.gif') ?>';
//]]>
</script>
<![endif]-->
<!-- --------------calls function getCssJsHtmlBefore that completes external scripts before local scripts-->
<?php echo $this->getCssJsHtmlBefore() ?>
<!-- --------------the rest is the same as app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/head.phtml-->
<?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
<?php echo $this->helper('core/js')->getTranslatorScript() ?>
<?php echo $this->getIncludes() ?>
```

(replace Namespace and Modulename/modulename with your values)